# Amazon Redshift データシェアリングはオブジェクトの定義を変更したらデータシェア領域も同期されるのか

Tags: aws, amazon-redshift

Amazon Redshiftのデータシェアリングで、プロデューサクラスターでテーブルやviewを、カラムの追加等で定義を変更した場合、自動的にデータシェア領域のテーブルやviewにも反映されるのでしょうか？

ALTER DATASHARE〜 ADD TABLEでデータシェア領域にオブジェクトを追加しますが、定義を変更した場合、再度上記コマンドを入力する必要があるのでしょうか？

お分かりになる方いましたら、ご回答頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

[英語版の方で回答を頂きました。](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72060602)

データシェアリングはテーブルへのinsertと同様、テーブルやビューの定義を変更してもコンシューマ側に自動反映されるようです。
ただし、テーブル名やビュー名等の名称を変更した場合は、再度データシェアに登録する必要があるようです。